# Docker (for Windows) does not mount volume

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to mount a directory with configuration files in my docker-compose.yml.

In my case it is logstash, which tells me the mounted directory is empty.
Loading a bash and `ls -la` in the parent directory shows that the `pipeline` directory is empty and is owned by root.

One weird thing is, that it worked a few days ago.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.6.3
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      - 8989:8989
    volumes:
      - C:/PROJECT_DIR/config/logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it better to try around with `docker` itself, as it gives more feedback

```
docker run --rm -it -v C:/PROJECT_DIR/config/logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/ docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.6.3
```

From here and some googling I found out I had to reset my shared drives credentials under "Docker for Windows" -> Settings... -> Shared Drives, because I had changed my windows domain user password.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your system username or password then you need to re-apply the credentials to get the volume mount working.

[image]